# Calculating the sum of negative numbers in a column?

Tags: linux, awk

Hi I have a file like this:

```
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_210  
AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C 0 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 -1 
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T A 2 -1 2 2 2 -1 -1 2 2 0
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T A 1 2 2 2 2 -1 2 2 2 0
```

And I want to calculate the sum of **negative** numbers form column 7th up to end (in real file I have 102 column):

I use `awk` for calculating the normal sum (and it works perfectly):

```
awk 'NR>1 {x+=$8}END{print x}' test.txt
```

but what I want to do is to calculate the sum of **negative numbers only**. and if there is no nagative I would like to have `0`.
so I would like to find an awk command that I run for each column and I get an out put of `0` or a negative number e.g `-1 -2 -3` and so on.

this is what I was trying:

```
awk '/^-/ {n++;x+=$9} END {print x}' test.txt
awk '/^-/ {x+=$9} END {print x}' test.txt
awk 'NR>1' test.txt | awk '/^-/ {x+=$9} END {print x}'
```

but I get nothing! no error and now answer!
I'm also trying to get an ideal output format:

```
562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_210 
0 -2 0 -1 0 -2 -1 0 0 -1
```

I tried several thing which I think are wrong basically:

```
awk 'NR>1 {for ($i=7;i<=NF;$i++) if (x ~ /^-/) x+=$i }END{print x}' test.txt
```

result: my computer swaps!

```
awk 'NR>1 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) x+=$i }END{print x}' test.txt
```

result: I get an irrelevant answer(the total sum of negative number in the file)!

But this is not really important. I just want the `awk` command to calculate the sum of **negative numbers** in each column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try harder, the last example you posted is quite close. This would sum the columns separately (if that's what you want):

```
awk 'NR == 1 {cols = NF-7; for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) {header[i-7]=$i; x[i-7]=0;} } 
     NR>1 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) x[i-7]+=$i }
     END{for(i=0; i<=cols; i++) print header[i], x[i]}' <file
```

Comment: can you recommend me a good tutorial or book so I can understand these things better?